How to register a default deserializer for generic types using the MongoDb C# driver
I have a custom IBsonSerializationProvider to provide a generic SerializerBase<List> for all IEnumerables of T
SerializerBase<List>:
/// <summary>
/// For when a collection type in the model may (in some circumstances) be stored as a single document type in MongoDb, rather than a collection
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class PossibleSingleDocumentDeserializer<T> : SerializerBase<List<T>>
    where T : class
{
    static readonly IBsonSerializer<List<T>> BaseListSerializer = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<List<T>>();
    static readonly IBsonSerializer<T> BaseTSerializer = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<T>();

    public override List<T> Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var type = context.Reader.GetCurrentBsonType();
        if (type == BsonType.Document)
        {
            return [BaseTSerializer.Deserialize(context)];
        }
        return BaseListSerializer.Deserialize(context, args);
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, List<T> value)
        => BaseListSerializer.Serialize(context, args, value);
}

IBsonSerializationProvider:
internal class CustomSerializerProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    public IBsonSerializer? GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        // Check if the type implements IEnumerable
        if (type.IsGenericType && typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            var elementType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var serializerType = typeof(PossibleSingleDocumentDeserializer<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
            return (IBsonSerializer?)Activator.CreateInstance(serializerType);
        }

        // Return null if this provider does not handle the requested type
        return null;
    }
}

I am registering it with BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new CustomSerializerProvider()); which works for serializing data but it doesn't get called to deserialize. I noticed internal class IBsonSerializationProvider requires a GetSerializer method, is there another class with a GetDeserializer method?
How would I register a default deserializer for generic types?
